# Import mysql database, ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I try to import a database on ubuntu, but I get a message and the DB is not imported, I am not sure why I get this message. That DB has +45MB.

[image]

```
mysqldump -u MYUSERNAME-p db_name< /var/www/html/path.sql
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the `mysqldump` command to load/import a SQL file?

Comment: `mysqldump` is used to *export* the DB not import it. After exporting you can import with the `mysql` program (I don't remember the syntax off the top of my head but I think it's similar (or identical) to how you wrote the `mysqldump` command; just replace "mysqldump" with "mysql")

Comment: Damn, you're right. With mysql, works, thank you!